# Understanding apache RewriteLog

Tags: apache, apache2

I'd like to understand the output from RewriteLog in apache2.
I have something like

...... (3) applying pattern '^/img(.*)' to uri '/api/marker/2'
...... (3) applying pattern '^/img/imagecache/(.+)' to uri '/api/marker/2'                                                                            .....  (1) pass through /api/marker/2
.... . (3) [perdir /some/path] add path info postfix: /some/path/marker -> /some/path/marker/2
.......(3) [perdir /some/path] strip per-dir prefix: /some/path/marker/2 -> marker/2

Those things in brackets (Example (1),(2) etc...,      the key phrases   "pass through" "applying pattern" "perdir"  prefix/postfix etc.
I don't see nothing in manual regarding this.

Answer (score 6):

I filed this as issue #49844 at Bugzilla: ["No documentation on the logging format of RewriteLog"](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49844)

Comment: Apache HTTPD Issue #49844 got updated with infos on the logging format: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49844#c1